# Divide large number by 1000 and round to one decimal place

Tags: ios, objective-c, rounding

I am finding it very difficult to do a simple operation, take a large number (4 digits or above) divide by 1000, round to one decimal place and then display as a string with K but perhaps I am missing an obvious answer.  (There are tons of questions on this on SO but no one seems to agree on a good answer.)

I would like the following to display as 5.6K.

```
    int startingint = 5654;
    int formatted = startingint/1000;
    NString *formattedstr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%dK", formatted];
```

Instead, it displays 5K.

Can anyone suggest how to get it to show an extra decimal place?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: "Instead, it displays 5K." Yes, because you are performing _integer division_. Think about it. You will _never_ get _any_ decimal places if you do that. You are getting an _integer_ (as your own code even tells you)! See http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch01.html#_operators

Comment: You may wish to look at `NSByteCountFormatter`. Save yourself the work of doing it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
float starting = 5654.0;
float formatted = starting/1000.0;
NString *formattedstr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1fK", formatted];
```